# How to make Mathematica Simplify Square Root Expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplify

I would like Mathematica to evaluate square root of a squared variable.  Instead it is just returning the squared variable under square root.  I wrote a simple code as an example:

```
x = y^2
z = FullSimplify[Sqrt[x]]
```

But it is returning y^2 under a square root sign!

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is documented on the `Sqrt` reference page:

> - `Sqrt[z^2]` is not automatically converted to *z*.
>
> […]
>
> - These conversions can be done using `PowerExpand`, but will typically be correct only for positive real arguments.

Thus:

```
In[1]:= x = y^2

Out[1]= y^2

In[15]:= PowerExpand[Sqrt[x]]

Out[15]= y
```

You can also get simplifications by supplying various assumptions:

```
In[10]:= Simplify[Sqrt[x], Assumptions -> Element[y, Reals]]

Out[10]= Abs[y]

In[13]:= Simplify[Sqrt[x], Assumptions -> y > 0]

Out[13]= y

In[14]:= Simplify[Sqrt[x], Assumptions -> y < 0]

Out[14]= -y
```

If you want more help, I suggest asking on [the Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).